# SQL: Group by specific time instead of year

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, group-by

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DATEPART(yyyy, ap.Date) AS 'Year', COUNT(p.Name2) AS 'Times entered', p.Name2 AS 'Name'       
FROM Person p  JOIN Price ap ON ap.PersonId = p.ID   
GROUP BY p.Name2, DATEPART(yyyy, ap.Date) 
ORDER BY DATEPART(yyyy, ap.Date) DESC , p.Name2 ASC
```

As result I have the following Data:

```
2018    50  Bob
2018    40  Fred
2017    10  Bob
2017    5   Fred
```

What I actually want is to not group by year, but to group by the period of between july 2017 and june 2018.

**I want to group by period of July 2017 to June 2018.**

How are we possible to set a timeframe as a group by function in SQL?

Comment: I am using SQL Server, sorry for the mistake. i edited the tags

Comment: "group by period of July 2017 to June 2018" - you can put the where clause before group by. Like, `FROM.. WHERE ap.DATE >=  '2017-07-01' and ap.DATE <= '2017-06-31' GROUP BY... `

Comment: @Selva, but if i use that, i will still have a group by by year, it will show me 2017 and 2018

Comment: How the data should be grouped? What is your actual expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT g.my AS 'Month-Year', 
       COUNT(p.Name2) AS 'Times entered', 
       p.Name2 AS 'Name'       
FROM Person p  
JOIN Price ap ON ap.PersonId = p.ID   
CROSS APPLY 
(
   SELECT CONCAT(DATEPART(mm, ap.Date), '-', DATEPART(yyyy, ap.Date)) AS my 
) AS g
WHERE ap.Date BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2018-06-30'
GROUP BY p.Name2, g.my
ORDER BY g.my DESC , p.Name2 ASC
```